# gassetic build --env=prod not watching for file changes

Tags: symfony, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm having an issue when running

gassetic build --env=prod

my gassetic.yml file has the followng

```
requires:
    compass : gulp-compass
    minify  : gulp-minify-css
    concat  : gulp-concat
    uglify  : gulp-uglify
mimetypes:
    # This section contains the formatters for the css files
    css:
        # In 'prod' mode, use these settings
        prod:
            outputFolder: web/css  # The output folder for your saving your compiled files
            webPath:      css  # The web path for the compiled files
        # Run these tasks on your compiled files
        tasks:
            - { name: compass, args: { sass: src/WebBundle/Resources/sass, css: web/css } }
            - { name: minify }
            - { name: concat, args: '%filename%' }
    # This is the list of source files to apply the above settings
        files:
            frontend.css: # This is the output filename
                - src/WebBundle/Resources/sass/*.scss

    # Watch these files for changes (optional)
    watch:
        - src/WebBundle/Resources/sass/*.scss
```

However after compiling the css there is no watcher watching the scss files in the specified location for changes.

Am I missing something from the gassetic.yml file?

Answer (score 1):

Gassetic starts the watcher and livereload only for the **dev** env. So if you have only one env, then use the **dev** instead of **prod**.

In the code then use `<!-- *:frontend.css -->` (see the * in there)

Comment: StackOverflow advertisement :D